# My wordpress plugin adds the data at the bottom of a page

Tags: wordpress

So i wrote a Wordpress plugin that generates a contact form based on your settings in the admin panel.

All well, but im having a major problem when displaying it.

I have created a shortcode [flexible_contact_form] that you add through the HTML editor in each page.

After I put the shortcode at the bottom of each page in the editor, the contact form always comes up at the top of the page.

[Here's an example](http://www.titanmotorcoach.com/24-passenger-mini-bus/).

Here's a part of the code that I use to display the contact form:

```
    <div class="cornered front" id="content">
<?php if ($small_desc != ""){ ?> <p><?php echo $small_desc;?></p> <?php } ?>
    <div id="formholder" >
        <form id="contact_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
......................
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem by only one way: Edit the plugin source.

Comment: I know but how can I get that fixed? what do i have to change?